# How to filter words with measurements in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program in Java to filter the words relative to measurements like:

```
100GB
88KB
78MB
10AM
11AM
1ST
2ND
30AM
4GB
6PM
9AM
```

I tried:

```
if (Pattern.compile("^[0_9*][(GB)(MB)(KB)]$")
            .matcher(words[i]).find())
```

But not working as expected.

Comment: Can you explain the way in which you _do_ expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the following regex:

```regex
\b\d+(?:KB|MB|GB|TB|AM|PM|ST|ND|RD|TH)\b
```

Explanation of regex:

```regex
\b               word boundary
\d+              match one or more digits
(?:
    KB|MB|GB|TB  size abbreviations
    |            or
    AM|PM        AM or PM
    |            or
    ST|ND|RD|TH  1ST, 2ND, 3RD, 4TH, etc.
)
\b               word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex have multiple problems, Try this regex instead:

```
 "^[0-9]+(GB|MB|KB)$"
```

This will match any number followed by GB or MB or KB

Regex demo https://regex101.com/r/CvHBIN/1

Comment: This doesn't cover things like `1ST` and `2ND`, which the OP seems to want to capture.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I know I try to correct the regex of the OP, if he want the others then all he/she need to do is `^[0-9]+(GB|MB|KB|ST|ND)$`